# Cakephp Pass array of checkboxes to another controller

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

What I'm trying to do is give users a way to checkout multiple products from the inventory.

My products index page (lists all available products to be checked out) looks like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('multi');?>
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
<tr class="hovertable">
    //All the fields go here
    <td style="cursor: default">
        <?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('tr/Checkouts_Add.png') . " " . __('Checkout'), array('controller' => 'Checkouts','action' => 'add', $product['Product']['id']), array('escape' => false, 'class' => 'button')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('tr/Edit.png'), array('action' => 'edit', $product['Product']['id']), array('escape' => false)); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->postLink($this->Html->image('tr/Delete.png'), array('action' => 'delete', $product['Product']['id']), array('escape' => false), __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $product['Product']['id'])); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Product.id.'.$product['Product']['id'] ,
            array('label' => false,
                  'type' => 'checkbox',
                  'id'=>'listing_'.$product['Product']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Submit'));?>
```

Then in my checkouts controller I've added a new function to checkout multiple items, I'd like this form to be populated by the checked products

```
    public function multi($count = 1) {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {            
        foreach($this->request->data['Checkout'] as $data) {
            //Do not forget this line. you need to create new model for saving each time.
            if ($this->request->isPost()) {
                $this->Checkout->create();
                $this->Checkout->save($data);
            } else {
                $this->request->data['Checkout']['product_id'] = $productId;
            }
        }
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $products = $this->Checkout->Product->find('list');
    $users = $this->Checkout->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('products', 'users'));
    $this->set('count', $count);
}
```

As you see I've tried to add hat I thought might work but the Submit button from the products index page does nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i just check several times and at least i understand one of the reason of your failure is inside of your foreach you have some `error` or `warning` as i don't know about the value of your product array i check this code and it worked well for me :

```
<?php $products=array('0'=>'11','1'=>'22','2'=>'333');
echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
<tr class="hovertable">
    //All the fields go here
    <td style="cursor: default">

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Product.id.'.$product,
            array('label' => false,
                  'type' => 'checkbox',
                  'id'=>'listing_'.$product)); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
 <?php
 endforeach;

echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
```

if you have no error or warning i suggest to you check without

> $this->Form->postLink